# Redirect 301 different for products and categories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need your help to do a 301 redirect e-commerce site. 
Products have to redirect to another folder but with the same format, which has no difficulty, but the categories have to change to end in "html" to "/".

Products:

> from www.domain.com/folder_A/product_name.html
>   to www.domain.com/product_name.html

Categories:

> from www.domain.com/folder_A/category_1/subcategory_1-1/subcategory_1-1-1.html
>   to www.domain.com/category_1/subcategory_1-1/subcategory_1-1-1/

Can you help me to make this redirect in htaccess?
I have more than 1500 categories and subcategories, so better if I have not to do the redirection of the categories one by one.

Comment: How to identify a product vs a category looking at URL?

Comment: The product name has only characters and underscores? the categories has numbers as surfix?

Comment: Of course this is the principal difficulty. The only difference between products and categories are the number of slashes. Except for the main categories who have the same number of slashes than products.

Comment: So `www.domain.com/folder_A/foobar.html` can be a product URL and a category URL as well?

Comment: Yes www.domain.com/folder_A/foobar.html can be a product URL and a category URL.

Comment: Yes www.domain.com/folder_A/foobar.html can be a product URL and a category URL. But this only occurs in main categories, so for they I could do a "personalized" redirection because are a few ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok based on discussion in comments section, you can try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# specific category pages
RewriteRule ^folder_A/(category_1|category_2|category_3)\.html$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]

# rest of the categories
RewriteRule ^folder_A/([^/]+/.+?)\.html$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]

# all products
RewriteRule ^folder_A/([^/.]+\.html)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry but don't work for me. I will try tomorrow again. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

#### For redirecting:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder_A/((.*)[0-9]).html$ http://www.domain.com/$1/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder_A/((.*)[^0-9]).html$ http://www.domain.com/$1.html
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think the order of rewrite rule will be inverse. The source URL of categories have ".html" at the end and the destination URL will have a trailing slash.

Comment: What does is when user enters `example.com/cat1/cat2/cat3/` in the browser address bar, it will show the contents of `example.com/folder_A/cat1/cat2/cat3.html`. Do you want that reversed?

Comment: Yes, I need that when a user enters example.com/folder_A/cat1/cat2/cat3.html be redirected to example.com/cat1/cat2/cat3/

Comment: I somehow missed that you want to redirect rather than doing a URL rewrite. I have changed my code to do 301 redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Finally a mixture of the two solutions provided by Kums and Anubhava has worked for me.

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder_A/([^/]+/.+?)\.html$ /$1/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder_A/([^/.]+\.html)$ /$1`

If I can ask you another favor, now these functions need to change from this format:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder_A/([^/]+/.+?)\.html$ /$1/`

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder_A/([^/.]+\.html)$ /$1`

To something like this:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} XXXXX
RewriteRule XXXXX [L,R=301]`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} XXXXX
RewriteRule XXXXX [L,R=301]`

This requested change is because with the first format (RedirectMatch) the destination URL appears with this text "?sef_rewrite=1" in the end, and after asking on e-commerce software forum it seems that the problem was this format related to this software.

Could you help me please to transform the firsts functions to "rewritecond" format?

Thank you very much